# Fetch отслеживание процесса отправки данных

Tags: javascript

как узнать сколько данных в каждую секунду было отправлено? в документации смотрел не нашел поскольку с английским знаком на базовом уровне этого не хватает

Comment: а вы уверены, что fetch этого не умеет?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я вроде спецификацию не писал моя информация основывается на том что изучаю(на https://learn.javascript.ru + mdn) если это не так можете дать пример?

Comment: [upload-progress-indicators-for-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711724)

Comment: Вам не надо спецификацию писать, вам надо ее читать :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я не смог найти инфу что feach это умеет и как если такое возможно можете дать конкретную ссылку на ту часть спецификации где это описано?